# How to perform random switch in Gatling Java

Tags: java, scala, switch-statement, gatling

Is it possible to perform a random switch to disperse load among requests, similarly to how it is done in Scala? I could not find any resources on how to do this in Java.

Example code:

```
    public static final ChainBuilder teacherCreateAssignmentsSetup = group("teacherCreatesAssignmentsSetup").on(
            exec(sessionSetSessionVariable)
                    .exec(session -> session.set("teacherRefId", getUniqueIdFromTokenSub(session)))
                    .exec(createEdCtsAssignment)
                    .exec(session -> {
                        log.info("assignment is :" + session.getString("studentsAssignment"));

                        return session;
                    })
                    .randomSwitch(
                            50.0 -> exec(nextRequest),
                            50.0 -> exec(anotherRequest)
                    )
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create WithWeight array.

```
                    .randomSwitch().on(
                            new Choice.WithWeight(50.0, exec(nextRequest)),
                            new Choice.WithWeight(50.0, exec(anotherRequest))
                    )
```